# Load twitter posts from different users

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, twitter-oauth

Hi need to load twitter posts from **different users**.
I know how to load post from single user.
Perform request with search query `FROM:<username>`.
Do you know the way how to load posts from different users?
I tried something like this `FROM:<username1>&&<username2>` - but it doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an approach. I have to use Twitter iOS SDK and `TWTRAPIClient` for performing the request. `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json` is endpoint for getting tweets of certain user with some username.

```
  NSURLRequest *r = [[TWTRAPIClient new] URLRequestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                                                URL:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"
                                                         parameters:@{@"screen_name":name}
                                                              error:nil];


        [[TWTRAPIClient new] sendTwitterRequest:r completion:^(NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable connectionError) {
            if(data){

                NSArray *tweets = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
                [TWTRTweet tweetsWithJSONArray:tweets]


            }
        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of TwitterKit framework which is available in cocoapods GitHub - https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios/wiki/Access-Twitter's-REST-API
Cocoapods - https://cocoapods.org/pods/TwitterKit
Its twitter's own library, so you can always rely on that.
To load multiple tweets you need to use the below code

```
let client = TWTRAPIClient()
let tweetIDs = ["510908888888487103", "510908133777777104"]
client.loadTweets(withIDs: tweetIDs) { (tweets, error) -> Void in
  // handle the response or error
}
```

If you want to to access other Twitter API endpoints, you can construct a request manually also like below

```
let client = TWTRAPIClient()
let statusesShowEndpoint = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json"
let params = ["id": "20"]
var clientError : NSError?

let request = client.urlRequest(withMethod: "GET", url: statusesShowEndpoint, parameters: params, error: &clientError)

client.sendTwitterRequest(request) { (response, data, connectionError) -> Void in
    if connectionError != nil {
        print("Error: \(connectionError)")
    }

    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
        print("json: \(json)")
    } catch let jsonError as NSError {
        print("json error: \(jsonError.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Hope this one helps.

Comment: I don't need multiple tweets. I need tweets from multiple users.

Comment: If you use the first chunk of code in my answer you can get tweets of multiple persons.